# Ubuntu 13.10 server has no kernels

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, images

Something has gone wrong and now we no longer have a Linux kernel (not even recovery mode) installed. GRUB is still there, but it runs the memory test.

How can I fix this? Everything I've looked at applies to 2010 or something silly.

Comment: Restore it from a backup?

Comment: Unfortunately there are no recent backups. That's what I believe has corrupted everything.

Comment: This site is for Professional Sysadmins, who take backups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link should help:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing

Basically, boot from a 13.10 live CD, reinstall your kernel (after making sure you where it and the relevant GRUB2 modules are supposed to be.

Hard to say but I'd guess you screwed up your EFI business in GRUB and now its lost.

Comment: Ok, I've mounted `/dev/skyler-vg/root` and ran `apt-get install linux-image-generic` restarted but GRUB isn't picking them up.

Comment: And you're using grub-install and checking your grub.conf?

Comment: Am I running grub-install from the `/mnt/skyler-vg/root`? I'm not particularly great with the GRUB side of Linux,

Comment: Your grub.conf matters more, make sure its pointing to efi modules if you're using them and then to your kernel, which is likely on a different part.

Comment: Since I'm booting into a Live CD, how can I find where the GRUB partition is? `fdisk -l`?

Comment: find / -name grub.conf from your mounted filesystem.  Make sure you also mount the other partitions under that (in case skyler-vg isn't the one where everything lives)  - usually /boot/grub2/grub.conf or similar, not sure about Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13603/discussion-between-james-and-quadruplebucky)

Comment: In the Chat you suggested Super GRUB. Although this hasn't fixed it, it has allowed me to boot Ubuntu!